# Selecting Paypal in checkout step then reviewing order details in the next step before placing the order

Tags: paypal

I'm looking for direction on documentation or others who have sites with the same scenario:

- step a: Select Payment - The user can selecting Paypal in checkout
- step b: Review Order details - The user has selected paypal in step 2
  and can review the order detail before placing the order with PayPal.

Questions:

1. Can step a just be a selection of the paypal payment method not leading to paypal sign in?
2. Or does step a have to be a sign into paypal
3. Once Signed into paypal, does the paypal api allow the user back to the site to allow to review (step b)?
4. Does initiating Paypal have to end with the placement of the order? i.e. it can not return to the step b to review , then complete the order?

Answer (score 0):

"Selecting" PayPal without signing in doesn't do anything, and accomplishes nothing. You should have a PayPal checkout/sign-in shortcut button as early as possible in your flow (ideally on a "view cart" page), in addition to the normal payment selection location. This allows payers to sign in quickly without having to type in any address information, which speeds the process. PayPal payers almost always already have their address saved at PayPal. The less friction there is in the process, the more likely a payer is to actually click through and complete the checkout. This increases sales measurably.

If you need a review step after PayPal before capturing, then you can show one after approval (in the 'onApprove' function) before doing the capture. If you are not going to be capturing immediately, the button text of the last action at PayPal should be changed from the default 'Pay Now' to say 'Continue'. To do so, when creating the order set a top level (not inside purchase units) `application_context` object with a `user_action` key of `CONTINUE`. This only changes the text of the button, it is up to you to make the behavior after approval match (and it must match).

To change the details of the PayPal order before capture, use an [Update Order Details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch) API call, which is an HTTP patch operation (not post) that gives no success response other than a 204 code.

---

For payer approval, [use this flow](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server); it has the necessary client-side error handling of a v2/checkout/orders capture response (restarting in case of a recoverable funding failure)